# Laravel5 passing route args as middleware args

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I would like the route argument to be passed as a middleware argument, something like this

```
Route::get('foo/{id}', ['middleware' => 'bar:{id}', function(){

});
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from the request variable:

```
Route::get('foo/{id}', ['middleware' => 'bar', function(){

});

public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
  $id = $request->id;
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-get-url-parameters-at-middleware?page=1

The

```
bar:id
```

is used when you want to pass the string `id` to the middleware.

Comment: Ok so there's not a direct way to bind route arg on a middleware arg.

Comment: No, but you don't need it. You can get it via the `$request` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the middleware up in the controller's constructor, it's possible to pass dynamic middleware variables.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('bar:'.request()->id);
}
```

Comment: yea, I was confused, disregard that. I think your answer (putting the middleware in the controller) is the only way to pass a route parameter through as an argument though.